# loading uitableviewcell with animation transition using swift 2

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, swift2

loading uitableviewcell with animation transition using swift 2

How to create animation for tableview cell when view is load ??

thanks in advance

Comment: Did you search before asking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use willDisplayCell delegate method of UITableView to animate cell
i am adding 3 animation you can apply any one of them

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        //MARK:- Fade transition Animation
        cell.alpha = 0
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.33) {
            cell.alpha = 1
        }

        //MARK:- Curl transition Animation
       // cell.layer.transform = CATransform3DScale(CATransform3DIdentity, -1, 1, 1)

       // UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4) {
          //  cell.layer.transform = CATransform3DIdentity
        //}

        //MARK:- Frame Translation Animation
        //cell.layer.transform = CATransform3DTranslate(CATransform3DIdentity, -cell.frame.width, 1, 1)

       // UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.33) {
          //  cell.layer.transform = CATransform3DIdentity
       // }
    }
```